# Win application on starting kills other running applications

Tags: windows-8.1

Whenever I start this particular application in my Win 8.1 , all other applications I had been running(eg. Media Player, MS Word, windows terminal ) is closed automatically by this new application. I guess it initiates a kill command for the running applications with a script file. How do I stop this application from killing other running applications?

Help will be appreciated.

Thanks

Basically it is an application which runs only when i insert an usb drive which contains the files reqd for running this application. The drive is write protected. The application initiates a mini portal with lectures and readable books(basically a study material).

Comment: Create an image of the drive, mount the image then remove the auto play and the application, then buy a new flash drive and apply the image to it

Comment: I guess it's some horrible DRM scheme that tries to prevent you copying from the USB ...

Comment: @Aditya - Which is the reason you have to remove the application, from being contained in the image, before you apply it to a new device.  I am pretty sure, I said that in my original comment, which means you didn't actually try my suggestion.

Comment: The drive is configured to **AutoPlay** the application is it not?  You said as much "which contains the files reqd for autoplay of this application."

Comment: You originally said that when you plugged in this device, a program would automatically start, that is controlled by AutoPlay.  If the program is ran manually, and by running it it closes applications, there is nothing you can do about that.

Comment: @Aditya - It is a trivial operation to determine what processes are running on the system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try using a sandbox application such as [Sandboxie](http://www.sandboxie.com) to prevent the application from interacting the external applications.

Comment: Its worked now. Thanks. This time time i put the application inside the sandbox.